# Modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this expression: $\tau=a+b \mod x$ and from this I want calculate $b$. From my side I obtain that $b=\tau \mod x - a \mod x$ but the solution is: $b=\tau - a \mod x$. Why ? I don't understand.

Comment: Apply the definition of $y$ mod $x$ to your initial expression and work in $\mathbb{Z}$. That's the easiest way until you get familiar with arithmetics in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, the worderful world of modulos - and that will help build your intuition and understanding of how modulos work.

Comment: The expression $a\equiv b \pmod{c}$ means that $a-b$ is divided by
$c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau=a+b\bmod x$ means that there is an integer $k$ such that $$\tau=a+b+kx.$$ Hence $b=\tau-a-kx$, that is,
$$
b\equiv \tau-a\bmod{x}.
$$